# Automating Slack Account Creation

Tags: api, automation, sdk, slack

My goal is to be able to create a slack account with the slack SDK/APIs somehow (given all the necessary information for the user). Is this possible?

The only thing I see in the documentation is working with users that have existing accounts, but maybe I can somehow get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into **[SCIM APIs](https://api.slack.com/scim)** of slack.

For user creation, you can try 
 **https://api.slack.com/scim#post-users**

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!